# Issue with XGboost in python

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

In python using Xgboost.sklearn.XGBclassifier, we have a parameter "n_estimators" for the number of trees which we can select while training the model, but I have not found any such parameter associated with xgboost.train(), Is there a way to add number of trees in xgboost.train()?

Answer (score 0):

Use num_boost_round

See also:

http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html

Comment: I guess, num_boost_round represents the number of boosting iterations for a single tree and I am asking about multiple trees for each boosting iteration. for example: like we can have multiple trees in random forest and the final results is either average out,majority voting etc.